# Correct bootstrap estimates from mixed-models estimated using GLMMadaptive package in R?

Tags: r, mixed-models, montecarlo

I have estimated a model using the `mixed_model()` function in the GLMMadaptive package. I then run `marginal_coefs()` to get estimates of the model coefficients.

However, I am interested in individual bootstrap estimates and not the summary with standard errors.

```
# Simulate data -----------------------------------------------------------

library(GLMMadaptive)
library(parameters)
set.seed(123)

n <- 500
K <- 15
t.max <- 25

betas <- c(-2.13, -0.25, 0.24, -0.05)
D <- matrix(0, 2, 2)
D[1:2, 1:2] <- c(0.48, -0.08, -0.08, 0.18)

times <- c(replicate(n, c(0, sort(runif(K-1, 0, t.max)))))
group <- sample(rep(0:1, each = n/2))
DF <- data.frame(year = times, group = factor(rep(group, each = K)))
X <- model.matrix(~ group * year, data = DF)
Z <- model.matrix(~ year, data = DF)

b <- cbind(rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D[1, 1])), rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D[2, 2])))
id <- rep(1:n, each = K)
eta.y <- as.vector(X %*% betas + rowSums(Z * b[id, ]))
DF$y <- rbinom(n * K, 1, plogis(eta.y))
DF$id <- factor(id)

# Fit model ---------------------------------------------------------------

fm1 <- mixed_model(fixed = y ~ year * group, random = ~ 1 | id, data = DF,
                   family = binomial())

fixef(fm1)
# (Intercept)         year       group1  year:group1 
# -2.875293208  0.204144801 -0.648693468 -0.006044763 
                   
marginal_coefs(fm1, std_errors = TRUE, cores = 1L)
# Estimate Std.Err  z-value p-value
# (Intercept)  -1.3589  0.1132 -12.0052 < 1e-04
# year          0.0966  0.0049  19.5229 < 1e-04
# group1       -0.3298  0.1593  -2.0701 0.03844
# year:group1  -0.0017  0.0060  -0.2795 0.77983
```

Running bootstrap functions from other packages such as the `simulate_model()` or `bootstrap_model()` functions from the *parameters* package gives different estimates, to me it looks like the fixef() estimates rather than marginal_coefs().

```
# Attempting bootstrap ----------------------------------------------------

boot1 <- simulate_model(fm1)

head(boot1)
# (Intercept)      year     group1  year:group1
# 1   -3.070493 0.2027782 -0.3007470 -0.025986201
# 2   -2.519327 0.1933386 -1.2355527  0.017103472
# 3   -2.961474 0.2018879 -0.9387294  0.005741996
# 4   -3.161030 0.2065284 -0.1132879 -0.003789857
# 5   -2.928608 0.2121623 -0.5544314 -0.017843094
# 6   -2.641134 0.2096486 -0.7674762 -0.009780880

boot2 <- bootstrap_model(fm1)

head(boot2)
# (Intercept)      year     group1  year:group1
# 1   -3.290467 0.2241487 -0.5442821 -0.014983360
# 2   -3.000414 0.2170271 -1.4123910  0.032449929
# 3   -3.151854 0.2250754 -0.5587116 -0.020200773
# 4   -2.871156 0.2075495 -0.8978337  0.002818839
# 5   -3.077286 0.2247614 -0.9924678  0.009701687
# 6   -3.362738 0.2402740 -0.7568267 -0.005283174
```

What is the appropriate bootstrap procedure for models such as the one above? Ideally I would like to get estimates that resemble the `marginal_coefs()` output rather than `fixef()`.